# Can i recover exodus with 12 words form blockchain.info?

Tags: blockchain.info, seed, mnemonic-seed

At btgexplorer i saw that i have some BTG. I want to claim it from by blockchain.info wallet. I followed this article https://medium.com/@kuzdogan/how-to-claim-your-bitcoin-gold-from-blockchain-info-or-other-wallets-e7ff4242ecf2 but i cannot use Coinomi wallet. I like to use exodus wallet.

If i recover my bitcoin wallet (with 12 words from blockchain.info) inside exodus, will i still be able to use my blockchain.info wallet?

Comment: If your blockchain.info wallet is new enough, you should be able to just import the seed into Exodus. If it's back from their custom formats, you will need to export and import individual keys, for which you should consult their support docs.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1. Create a new blockchain.info wallet (or better yet, a wallet where *you* control the private keys)
2. Send all the BTC from your existing blockchain.info wallet into your new wallet.
3. Use your recovery phrase to generate any BTG-compatible wallet.  That should allow that wallet to "see" the BTG balance associated with that private key.

It's important to create a new wallet for your existing BTC since the 12 word passphrase is the *only* secret required to access those funds.  Creating a new wallet creates a new private key, which results in a new 12-word passphrase, thereby protecting your existing BTC (assuming you send it to the new BTC wallet).